# Laravel Get Data From Relation Table

Tags: mysql, laravel, model, tags, laravel-7

I'm building a project with Laravel 7.28. I have three tables named; projects, tags and project_tags. in project_tags table there is project_ids and tag_ids. It looks like this:

[image: database_schema]

I need to get all projects with their tag and secondly I need to get projects with certain tag. So What should I do in models? Which function and how should I use? And how can I get data?

I discovered rtconner/laravel-tagging package but is it the correct way to do it? Thanks for your help

Comment: try many to many https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many and eager loading https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Rather than try packages, read the documentation about eloquent and eloquent relationships so you get a better understanding on how to work with related tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to create a [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship between projects and tags.

```php
class Project extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'project_tags')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Then:

```php
// Get all projects with their tags.
Project::with('tags')->get();

// Get projects contain certain a certain tag.
Project::whereHas('tags', function ($query) {
    return $query->where('tag', 'some value');
})
```

In addition, tags tend to be a [polymorphic many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) relationships. So if you want to manually handle tagging in the long term, I suggest designing that way.

Also, checkout [spatie/laravel-tags](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-tags) package.

Comment: when I run this, I get all projects but I only got 2 projects with this tag.  Have I done smt wrong?